# Numerically evaluate triple integral with non-constant limits

Tags: python, scipy, quad

Numerically evaluate triple integral with non-constant limits.

I want to numerically perform a triple integral of a two-variable function`f(x,y)` where both x and y have integration limits [a+t0-t,b+t0-t] and the third integral goes over t with integration limits [t0,t0+a]. I have tried following several examples using tplquad or nquad from scipy.integrate but nothing seems to work... This is my previous attempt:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad, dblquad, tplquad, nquad

def f(x, y):
    # Define your function f(x, y) here
    return x + y  # Example function: x + y

def integrate_function(a, b, t0):
    # Define the limits of integration
    x_lower = lambda t: a + t0 - t
    x_upper = lambda t: b + t0 - t
    y_lower = lambda x, t: a + t0 - t
    y_upper = lambda x, t: b + t0 - t
    t_lower = t0
    t_upper = t0 + a

    # Perform the triple integration
    result, _ = tplquad(f, t_lower, t_upper, y_lower, y_upper, x_lower, x_upper)

    return result

# Example usage
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
t0 = 0
result = integrate_function(a, b, t0)
```

Which yields the error:

```
TypeError: integrate_function.<locals>.<lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 't'
```

My current attempt is able to evaluate a double integral using nquad:

```
def f(x, y):
    return x*y

def bounds_y(t0, a):
    return [t0, t0+a]

def bounds_x(y,a,b,t0):
    return [a+t0-y, b+t0-y]

def integrate(a,b,t0):
    return nquad(f, [lambda y: bounds_x(y,a,b,t0), bounds_y(t0,a)])

integrate(2,5,0)
```

Unfortunately when I try to implement a third integral:

```
def f(x, y, t):
    return 1

def bounds_t(t0, a):
    return [t0, t0+a]

def bounds_x(y,a,b,t0):
    return [a+t0-y, b+t0-y]

def integrate(a,b,t0):
    return nquad(f, [lambda t: bounds_x(t,a,b,t0), lambda t: bounds_x(t,a,b,t0), bounds_t(t0,a)])

integrate(2,5,0)
```

it gives the error `TypeError: integrate.<locals>.<lambda>() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Comment: It might help to compare the lambda functions provided to [the requirements](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html). I think you've got them in the wrong order.

Comment: @tadman I think so... I wouldn't know what is wrong with them...

Comment: It might help to match them up to the arguments using labels, like `gfun=...`, or even better, specify those inline, like `gfun=lambda ...`

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this does the trick:

```
def f(x, y, t):
    return x*y

def bounds_t(t0, a):
    return [t0, t0+a]

def bounds_x(y,a,b,t0):
    return [a+t0-y, b+t0-y]

def integrate(a,b,t0):
    return nquad(f, [lambda t,x: bounds_x(t,a,b,t0), lambda t: bounds_x(t,a,b,t0), bounds_t(t0,a)])

integrate(2,5,0)
```

Comment: For your first bound (which are the bounds for `x`), I think you want `lambda y, t: ...` instead of `lambda t, x: ...`. Using `x` in place of `y` for the name is harmless, of course, but using `t, y` in place of `y, t` will end up doing the wrong integration.

Comment: Will it do a wrongful integration because it integrates ``t`` instead of ``y`` or because it integrates ``x`` and ``y`` is the wrong order?

Comment: SciPy will pass the value of `y` as the first argument to that bound, so your bounds for `x` will effectively become `a + t0 - y` and `b + t0 - y` instead of `a + t0 - t` and `b + t0 - t`.

Answer (score 0):

It does indeed require some careful reading of the documentation to use `nquad` and `tplquad` correctly. Here are solutions to your integration problem via both `nquad` and `tplquad`:

```py
from scipy.integrate import tplquad, nquad


def f(x, y, t):
    return x * y


def integrate_via_tplquad(a, b, t0):
    t_lower = t0
    t_upper = t0 + a
    y_lower = lambda t: a + t0 - t
    y_upper = lambda t: b + t0 - t
    # Note order of parameters here: (t, y) rather than (y, t)
    x_lower = lambda t, y: a + t0 - t
    x_upper = lambda t, y: b + t0 - t
    result, _ = tplquad(f, t_lower, t_upper, y_lower, y_upper, x_lower, x_upper)
    return result


def integrate_via_nquad(a, b, t0):
    t_bounds = (t0, t0 + a)
    y_bounds = lambda t: (a + t0 - t, b + t0 - t)
    # Order of parameters (y, t) is opposite to that used in tplquad.
    x_bounds = lambda y, t: (a + t0 - t, b + t0 - t)
    result, _ = nquad(f, [x_bounds, y_bounds, t_bounds])
    return result


print("Result via tplquad: ", integrate_via_tplquad(2, 5, 0))
print("Result via nquad: ", integrate_via_nquad(2, 5, 0))
```

When I run the above on my machine, I get:

```
Result via tplquad:  118.50000000000001
Result via nquad:  118.50000000000001
```

Note that it's really important to get the order of parameters right, and that to make matters worse the conventions for `tplquad` and `nquad` are opposite. If you accidentally reverse `y` and `t` in the bounds for `x` in either solution, you get an incorrect answer:

```
Result via tplquad:  25.499999999999996
Result via nquad:  25.499999999999996
```

If you're using `nquad`, you could also pass `a`, `b` and `t0` directly as arguments to the integrand and the bound functions instead of having to use the closures above. Here's what that looks like:

```py
def integrand(x, y, t, a, b, t0):
    return x * y

def x_bounds(y, t, a, b, t0):
    return a + t0 - t, b + t0 - t

def y_bounds(t, a, b, t0):
    return a + t0 - t, b + t0 - t

def t_bounds(a, b, t0):
    return t0, t0 + a

print("Result via nquad (2): ", nquad(integrand, [x_bounds, y_bounds, t_bounds], (2, 5, 0)))
```

The result on my machine:

```
Result via nquad (2):  (118.50000000000001, 1.3156142841808107e-12)
```